# numero primo con recursion

Tags: c++

No se porque este código explota en tiempo de ejecución, alguna idea?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

bool esPrimo(int number, int cont = 1, int div = 0)
{
    if (number % cont == 0) 
    {
        div+=1;
    } 
    else if (cont == number) {
        return (div < 3) ? 1: 0;
    }
    return esPrimo(number, cont++, div);
}

int main()
{
    int primo = esPrimo(3);
    cout << primo << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

No se si entendi bien la parte de los parametros `esPrimo(int number, int cont = 1, int div = 0)`, **el problema que tengo es con la sintaxis** y el hecho de que con la recursion no puedo almacenar los datos una vez se haya ejecutado la funcion, asi que para eso le asigno de nuevo estas variables en los parametros, hasta donde entendi, al inicializarlos en el mismo parametro hace permitible que ya no los llame, porque se irian reemplazando. Pero no estoy muy seguro. 
Lo que quiero conseguir es usar una funcion esPrimo() que **no llame mas de un parametro en main** y que **no use variables externas, punteros, referencias ni listas**. Si pueden ayudarme, les estaria agradecido.

Comment: Son necesarios almenos dos parametros o en el peor de lo cosas usar una variable global que este fuera del ambito de la funcion.

Comment: @Crack81 no quiero usar variables globales estaria muy facil resolverlo si no... y eso es lo que estaba preguntando, esa parte de los parametros, se puede obviar segun lo que lei.

Comment: puedes usar minimo 2 parametros menos ya no se puede.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Solución 1: usa variables **estáticas**.

No usamos nada fuera de la función, y ésta solo recibe 1 parámetro:

```
#include <iostream>

bool esprimo( int x ) {
  static int tmp = 0;

  if( x == 1 ) {
    tmp = 0;
    return true;
  }

  if( !tmp ) {
    tmp = x;
    --x;
  }

  if( !( tmp % x ) ) {
    tmp = 0;
    return false;
  }

  return esprimo( --x );
}

int main( void ) {
  using namespace std;

  cout << "esprimo( 3 ) = " << esprimo( 3 ) << endl;
  cout << "esprimo( 7 ) = " << esprimo( 7 ) << endl;
  cout << "esprimo( 10 ) = " << esprimo( 10 ) << endl;

  return 0;
}
```

> esprimo( 3 ) = 1
> esprimo( 7 ) = 1
> esprimo( 10 ) = 0

Las variables `static` tienen un tiempo de vida igual al tiempo de vida de tu aplicación. Es lo mismo que las declararas *fuera* de `main( )`, y conservan *para siempre* el último valor que les asignes. Al declararla *dentro* de una función, no aseguramos que no sea *vista* desde otros puntos del código, con lo que ganamos seguridad.

#### Solución 2: argumentos con valor por defecto.

Si te fijas, tu problema indica

> que no llame mas de un parametro en `main`

**No** se indica que la función solo reciba 1, sino que se llame desde `main( )` con 1.

```
#include <iostream>

bool esprimo( int x, int tmp = 0 ) {
  if( x == 1 )
    return true;

  if( !tmp ) {
    tmp = x;
    --x;
  }

  if( !( tmp % x ) )
    return false;

  return esprimo( --x, tmp );
}

int main( void ) {
  using namespace std;

  cout << "esprimo( 3 ) = " << esprimo( 3 ) << endl;
  cout << "esprimo( 7 ) = " << esprimo( 7 ) << endl;
  cout << "esprimo( 10 ) = " << esprimo( 10 ) << endl;

  return 0;
}
```

> esprimo( 3 ) = 1
> esprimo( 7 ) = 1
> esprimo( 10 ) = 0

En C++ se permiten argumentos con **valores por defecto**. Si al llamar a la función no les asignas tu un valor directamente, el compilador los pone *en tu lugar*. Eso quiere decir que la función **sigue recibiendo el número de argumentos indicado**, aunque no lo indiquemos explicitamente. Su misión es facilitar el uso de las funciones, ahorrandonos el escribir argumentos que, la mayoría de las veces, serán siempre el mismo ... o, como en este caso, proporcionar funcionalidad *no documentada*. Para cualquiera que no vea el código, la función `esprimo( )` solo recibe 1 argumento.

Comment: muchas gracias por tu tiempo, la verdad nunca me indicaron que era un problema, yo solito me lo formule, no que no entendia y me hubiera gustado que expliques es esa parte de inicializar variables como parametros en la implementacion de la funcion. La duda que tengo es que si llamo la funcion de nuevo, se reinicia el valor? o se reemplaza? Y otra pregunta, cual es la diferencia entre static y const?

Comment: @RenatoA. edité la respuesta, con una muy breve explicación. Lo de `const` ... es mas largo. Piensa que se puede usar en varios contextos. Creo que había una pregunta ya sobre el tema, pero no la encuentro :-(

Answer (score 0):

El argumento `div` no es necesario. Además, hay que empezar a chequear por 2 como divisor, porque todo número es divisible por 1 y luego daría siempre false. Además pasar `cont++` es incorrecto porque actualiza el valor de `cont` en la llamada recursiva. Lo correcto es pasar `cont+1` o primero hacer `cont++` y luego pasar `cont` en la llamada recursiva.

```
bool esPrimo(int number, int cont = 2)
{
    if (number % cont == 0 || number < 2) 
    {
        return false;
    } 
    else if (cont > number/2)
    {
        return true;
    }
    return esPrimo(number, cont+1);
}
```

Comment: Hola ian Mejias tu codigo no cumple lo que pide el OP ya que prentende usar solo un parametro al momento de llamar la funcion y no dos como en tu caso.

Comment: La funcion se llama con solo 1 parametro @Crack81. En el 'main' se llama como `esPrimo(17)` por ejemplo, el segundo parámetro es opcional.